# npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Nuwanst\package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, node-modules

I just want to install socket.io to my project which is located on 3.chat folder. But when I run following command it shows following Warnings.And its not created a node_modules directory inside my project folder. How to fix this?

```
C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\NodeJS\3.chat>npm install socket.io
C:\Users\Nuwanst
`-- socket.io@2.0.3

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Nuwanst\package.json'
npm WARN Nuwanst No description
npm WARN Nuwanst No repository field.
npm WARN Nuwanst No README data
npm WARN Nuwanst No license field.
```

Comment: make sure you have extracted the zip file correctly

Comment: For those trying to run `npm init`, `npm i` is _not_ a shorthand of it!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Have you created a **package.json** file? Maybe run this command first again.

`C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\NodeJS\3.chat>npm init`

It creates a **package.json** file in your folder.

Then run,

`C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\NodeJS\3.chat>npm install socket.io --save`

The `--save` ensures your module is saved as a dependency in your **package.json** file.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks!  Note that when you run "npm init" it will ask you to enter a lot of fields, but the default values are in parenthesis.  Just enter through and accept defaults.

Comment: Most of the cases this is not the correct answer. Please check @Aravin's answer

Comment: Aravin's answer is also wrong. There's a reason there is a `package-lock.json`. Deleting it doesn't solve the problem. What if this fails in your CI pipeline for example?

Comment: this also worked for me, but do i need to do this on every new clone of the project ? Also, what is wrong with old package.json why it needs to get recreated ?

Answer (score 181):

If you already have `package-lock.json` file just delete it and try again.

Comment: Rsynced all my apps from one server to another and package-lock.json was present there. Deleting it from all apps saved my day.

Comment: Don't add this to source control I am guessing?

Comment: Yes, this file should be added to `.gitignore` file

Comment: I don't have package-lock.json.

Comment: This worked for me after deleting the package-lock.json. Now my question is will the package-lock.json be reacreted after running npm instal? @Aravin Because  I am in he install process and i am not seeing it creating the the package-lock.json

Comment: Thanks it was added after the installation

Comment: it worked for me, but can you explain this solution?

Comment: Glad to know that @RégisNIOX

Comment: This file *should* be added to source control. In order to install from it instead of from `package.json` one can use `npm ci`.

Comment: Never delete the package-lock.json, there is a reason for it to exist. Deleting it will not solve your issues.

Answer (score 38):

Make sure you are on the right directory where you have package.json

Comment: Easy... but saved my day...

Comment: This was it for me.  For some reason I had two project directories, i.e. C:\project_1\project_1) and I was trying to npm start on the first one, which had no package.json

Answer (score 10):

You need to make sure that the `package.json` file exist in the `app` directory. Run this command where `package.json` file exists.

For more explanation, I run `npm start` in `c:\selfPractice`, but my `package.json` is in `c:\selfPractice\frontend`. When I switch to `c:\selfPractice`, it works.

Answer (score 6):

NOTE: if you are experiencing this issue in your CI pipeline, it is usually because npm runs `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. `npm ci` requires an accurate `package-lock.json`.

To fix this, whenever you are modifying packages in `package.json` (e.g. moving packages from devDependencies to Dependencies like I was doing) you should regenerate `package-lock.json` in your repository by running these commands locally, and then push the changes upstream:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
git commit package-lock.json
git push
```

Answer (score 4):

finally, I got a solution if you are getting:-

```
**npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory,.......**
```

then it is no issue of npm or its version it is os permission issue to resolve this you need to use below command:-

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER *
```

additional

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

then run:-

```
sudo npm i
```

Comment: Please don't run `sudo chmod -R 777 *` on your workspace.

Comment: this is quite dangerous, some people have no clue, you are recommending to give all rights to every file

Answer (score 4):

> If your folder already have `package.json`

Then,

Copy the path of `package.json`

Open terminal

Write:

`cd your_path_to_package.json`

Press `ENTER`

Then Write:

`npm install`

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Delete `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file

Then type `npm init`

after that type `npm install socket.io --save`

finally type `npm install`

**It works for me**

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to `npm install` on a folder that's being `rsync`'d from somewhere else, remember to add this to your `rsync --exclude`

```
yourpath/node_modules
```

Otherwise, NPM will try to add `node_modules` and rsync will remove it immediately, causing many `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open` errors.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this error but on looking for the answer online here on stackoverflow I found the answer in the process so I decided to share it also , If this error occurs on a react project you are working on and when you run `npm start` make sure to change directory into the directory that has react installed in it and it will start working

Answer (score 1):

I had this in a new project on Windows. `npm install` had created a `node_modules` folder for me, but it had somehow created the folder without giving me full control over it. I gave myself full control over `node_modules` and `node_modules\.staging` and it worked after that.

Comment: What are the steps to give yourself full control?

Comment: @KinleyChristian right click on the folder, select Properties, then go into the security tab.

Answer (score 1):

update `version` in package.json is working for me

Answer (score 0):

if your node_modules got installed in say /home/UserName/ like in my case,
your package-lock.json file will also be there. just delete this file, go back to your app folder and run `npm init` and then `npm install <pkgname>` (e.g express) and a new node_modules folder will be created for your.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have installed express in root directory.Copy path of package.json and delete package json file and node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved by removing all insignificant lines in packages.json e only left "name", "version", "description", "devDependencies", "dependencies", "resolutions". and the error was gone.

[image: The result package working is this]

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. In my case it was directory permissions issue . I cloned using visual studio git plugin. It was solved once i cloned from git command line in another folder and executed git install there

Answer (score -2):

the file path you ran is wrong. So if you are working on windows, go to the correct file location with cd and rerun from there.

Comment: Post a code along with the reason for better understanding.