# Getting error while installing udev module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, udev, node-serialport

I'm runnig command :

```
npm install udev
```

And I'm getting this error:

> ```
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mitesh/package.json'
> npm WARN mitesh No description
> npm WARN mitesh No repository field.
> npm WARN mitesh No README data
> npm WARN mitesh No license field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! udev@0.6.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the udev@0.6.0 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /home/mitesh/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T11_44_35_032Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Have you already run `npm init`?  Seems like it can't find your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have a package.json in your project or it is probably not rightly placed. Here is what you can do;

Browse to your project directory and run this command;

`npm init`

This should create a package.json file in your project directory

Then run,

`npm install udev --save`

`--save` will ensure your module is saved as a dependency in your package.json file.

you could just try to run the last command without  the `--save` but in some cases it helps

Here is a link to further assist: [npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Nuwanst\package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531633/npm-warn-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-c-users-nuwanst-packag)

Try this let me know if it helps.

Comment: I able to install udev module using this repository https://github.com/ConnectionSystems/node-udev